Would it be considered inappropriate or impermissible ex parte communication if no legal procedure has yet been initiated on the discussed matter?
The NYC Civil Court’s glossary defines “ex parte”:

ex parte: a proceeding, order, motion, application, request, submission etc., made by or granted for the benefit of one party only; done for, in behalf of, or on application of one party only

It also defines a “party” to be:

party: person having a direct interest in a legal matter, transaction or proceeding

Let’s say there’s an action the mayor of a town wants to take. They expect some group to object to said action and have some suspicion the issue may be litigated in court by the aforementioned objector group. The town counsel may want to “get ahead” of the issue and speak with a justice to find out how they might rule on the hypothetical lawsuit against the proposed action.
If the case was actively being litigated in some way, this undoubtedly would run afoul of any reasonable code of ethics regarding inappropriate ex parte communications.
However, by my layman’s understanding, it seems for any communication to be actually considered inappropriately ex parte there must be a party which was excluded from said communications. Further, it seems one can only be considered a party when there is actual, active (or in some jurisdictions, “impending”) procedure occurring involving them.
To that end, is it possible for a conversation to be considered inappropriately ex parte if the discussion centers on a case that, at the time, is only hypothetical or speculative of something that the court could hear in the future?

Asked differently, consider the following fact pattern:

Alice and Bob purchase a house in Smalltown. They pay a significant premium for the property because of its unobstructed view of Smalltown’s sprawling public park directly abutting it.
While going about their days, Alice and Bob are regularly visible to park-goers through their window, often unclothed. These sightings are brief in length and neither engage in anything lewd our obscene in view of the window.
Constituents begin to put pressure on Smalltown’s elected officials to take action to curb the park-visiting public’s visibility of Alice and Bob’s indecency.
Since this behavior on private property & behind closed doors is not explicitly prohibited by law in Smalltown’s jurisdiction, Smalltown law enforcement declines to intervene.
Smalltown’s mayor and her advisors have the idea to plant 20-foot-tall trees only along the edge of the park which directly abuts Alice and Bob’s house. Other houses similarly situated along the edge of the park will otherwise remain undisturbed.
The officials assess there is a 50% chance that Alice and Bob have the will and resources to initiate civil action against the town. The resulting litigation and possible rulings against the town would be extraordinarily negative for Smalltown’s finances, so the group tasks the town attorney to assess the winnability of a possible lawsuit.
Smalltown’s town attorney discusses these points with the municipal court judge to assess how they may rule on such a case.
After this discussion, Smalltown plants the trees, and Alice and Bob file a civil suit seeking to either have the trees removed or recover damages relative to the impact on the value of their property.

Does the bolded action somehow constitute an improper ex parte conversation which could jeopardize any initial ruling in favor of the town on appeal?

Alice and Bob don't have a case to bring against smalltown in the first place: there is no right to a specific panorama.

@Trish A clever lawyer might get around that, as the city may have various rules it's supposed to follow they might skirt or ignore (e.g. environmental assessments, public notice and debate periods, specific regulations on parks, etc.), from which standing may then be derived. Depending on how the planting/installation is done they may also suffer property damage or trespass, which may also be sufficient. As the action is targeted at them specifically they might try to stretch this into a discrimination claim if they are also a protected class. A difficult sell, but enough for standing maybe.

Wouldn't Alice and Bob have to deal with public decency laws? Just because they are doing something in their own home they still have an obligation to make sure it isn't disturbing others outside of their house which it clearly is in this case.

@JoeW as a member of the public, you are not supposed to take a peek into private residence in the first place. It is not like they are arguing loudly or shooting guns from their front porch or sunbathing in the nude in their front yard.  If you do decide to take a gander into someone's house, you might find them in the buff as they go through their day. In that case, the person looking is being a voyeur and the person nude in their own home is not being publicly indecent.

@jo1storm that depends on how the law is worded: in germany, if a spot is visible to the public, even inside a building or garden, then you can be fined for public indecency there.

@Trish yeah, but Germany is weird about public indecency and general standards of nudity. A woman walking topless in Germany might not be fined for public indecency depending on which part of Germany, even if she is walking in public park for example.  Depending on the park and local ordinance. There's quite a sharp divide between nudity, sexualization and public indecency in Germany.

@jo1storm Not sure you could exactly call it peaking through windows if it is said they are visible to park goers which would assume they are a distance away from the house. Also at that point even if people are actually peaking they would have some responsibility to prevent it.

@all none of this is relevant to the question asked, which is about the appropriateness and legality of asking a judge about a legal issue before it is in front of the court. Use [chat] instead.

Judges don’t give legal advice
You can’t approach a judge in their capacity as a judge and ask them how they might rule on a particular case. Courts in common law jurisdictions only decide disputes - they don’t give opinions. Any attorney, small town or big town, who approached a judge with such a request is skirting right on if not over the edge of legal malfeasance. Any judge who answered would be well over.
Now, judges wear multiple hats, particularly in small towns, and a judge might also have a legal practice or be a university lecturer depending on the rules of the jurisdiction. Approaching them in that capacity would be fine - but they would have to recuse themselves if the case ever came before them as a judge.
So, in the circumstances above, small town lawyer makes their own assessment or possibly consults big town lawyer for a second opinion. They can, of course, take what they know about the possible judges’ proclivities into account, but the can’t approach a judge.

My understanding—as a layman—is that, while this is not allowed, it’s disallowed by different legal concepts/codes than those against ex parte communication. Stating explicitly whether or not “ex parte” does or doesn’t would seem to improve this answer, since the question focuses on that so much. Obviously “something blocks this behavior” is the more salient point, but the question did ask whether or not “ex parte” was that something. (Though I think this would improve the answer, note I have upvoted regardless.)
